# Tried to do 3 dimensional matrix using malloc

Tags: c, matrix, malloc

I want to collect a 3-dimensional matrix using `malloc`. There is also the matrix printing part but I did not include that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
   int i,j,k,m,n,o;
   float ***A;
   printf("Input dimension for matrix(m,n,o)\n");
   printf("Enter m : ");
   scanf("%d",&m);
   printf("Enter n : ");
   scanf("%d",&n);
   printf("Enter o : ");
   scanf("%d",&o);
   A = (float***)malloc(o*sizeof(float**));
   for(i=0;i<o;i++){
           A[i] = (float**)malloc(m*sizeof(float*));
           for(j=0;j<m;j++){
               A[i][j] = (float*)malloc(n*sizeof(float));
           }
   }
   for(i=0;i<o;i++){
       for(j=0;j<m;j++){
           for(k<0;k<n;k++){
               printf("Input number for (%d,%d,%d) : ",j+1,k+1,i+1);
               scanf("%f",&A[i][j][k]);
           }
       }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Program seems to be skipping to the end after I finish input m,n,o, so I cannot enter any value of matrix. I have to use `malloc` because it was required for the task.

EDIT: everything that is wrong. m is for row,n is for column, and o is for a number of mXn matrix.

Comment: Shouldn't the first loop `for(i=0;i<n;i++)` be `for(i=0;i<o;i++)` because you allocated `o` array elements? And the following too.

Comment: you seem to be using different numbers for malloc and for your `for` loops. E.g. if dimensions are 111,222,333 then you allocate 111 float**s and then put 222 pointers into that space.

Comment: You've confused the issue by editing the code. Which is the *actual* code you have used? Please copy/paste the exact code you used.

Comment: @WeatherVane I edit of what you ask in this and actual code. But it didn't fix.

Comment: Please don't make the code a "moving target"!

Comment: Watch out for compiler warnings. `scanf("%f",A[i][j][k])` is wrong, it should be `&A[i][j][k]`

Comment: Next compiler warning is `for(k<0;k<m;k++)` ***enable all warnings***

Comment: I edit all wrong and this is the actual code now.

Comment: Secret Number, Are you required to use the [unnecessary cast](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605856/2410359) with `malloc()`?

Comment: You could optionally just do a `malloc(m * n * o * sizeof(float))` and just do some simple arithmetic to find the correct index. I prefer this for structures like these, because it will be a single `malloc` and a single `free`, no nasty loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you did is messed up in the for loop while taking the inputs. As per the context, the 3D matrix, I debugged the code and came up with a version that makes sense.

I will go on and point out the mistakes you made one by one.

First, `scanf` takes the memory address of the variable not the dereferenced version of it.

So, change it from this, `scanf("%f",A[i][j][k]);` to this `scanf("%f",&(A[i][j][k]));`. This one would also work `scanf("%f",A[i][j] + k);`.

In this line, `for(k<0;k<n;k++)`, `k` is not even initialized. So you are essentially operating on a garbage value. As my mind was already baffled by deciphering the `c pointer hell`, I couldn't even process the end result. Code that would make more sense is this `for(k=0;k<n;k++)`.

After that, you switched the control logic of the nested `for` loops.

Replace the variable `m` in this code `for(j=0;j<m;j++)` with `n`. `for(j=0;j<n;j++)`

Do vice-versa in the next loop. Modify this `for(k=0;k<n;k++)` to this `for(k=0;k<m;k++)`.

The final code would look like this,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
   int i,j,k,m,n,o;
   float ***A;
   printf("Input dimension for matrix(m,n,o)\n");
   printf("Enter m : ");
   scanf("%d",&m);
   printf("Enter n : ");
   scanf("%d",&n);
   printf("Enter o : ");
   scanf("%d",&o);
   A = (float***)malloc(o*sizeof(float**));
   for(i=0;i<o;i++){
           A[i] = (float**)malloc(n*sizeof(float*));
           for(j=0;j<n;j++){
               A[i][j] = (float*)malloc(m*sizeof(float));
           }
   }
   for(i=0;i<o;i++){
       for(j=0;j<n;j++){
           for(k=0;k<m;k++){
               printf("Input number for (%d,%d,%d) : ", i + 1, j + 1, k + 1);
               scanf("%f",&(A[i][j][k]));
           }
       }
   }
   
   
   return 0;
}
```

It would now work as a 3D matrix.

To understand the code I had to draw a messy diagram. I am attaching that. It may be of some help.

[image: diagram]

As you have already omitted some code I hope you have not forgotten to use `free` to prevent memory leaks.

Comment: Oh yeah. I didn't see the k<0 one. Thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

Use dynamic Variable-Length Array:

```
float (*A)[n][m] = calloc(o, sizeof *A);
```

And free it at the end with

```
free(A);
```

More one must passed an address of the scanf-ed object, not it's value. It should be:

```
scanf("%f", &A[i][j][k])
```

Comment: Sorry. But float A*** cannot be remove from the code. So i can't using the dynamic VLA.

Comment: @SecretNumber This is away to allocate for a 3D array.  `float A***` approach  is _not_ a 3D array, but an array of pointers to an array of pointers to an array of `float`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica My homework task is fixed for `float A***`. So I have to used that method instead.

Comment: @SecretNumber OK, so you do not want a true 3D array as titled, but a [jagged array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array).  Sorry if your course is not using crisp terms.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    float ***A;

    // n1, n2 and n3 will contain the three dimensions (i.e.: A[n1][n2][n3])
    size_t n1, n2, n3;

    printf("Insert first dimension: ");
    if (scanf("%zu", &n1) != 1) {
        printf("ERROR: cannot read number\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Insert second dimension: ");
    if (scanf("%zu", &n2) != 1) {
        printf("ERROR: cannot read number\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Insert third dimension: ");
    if (scanf("%zu", &n3) != 1) {
        printf("ERROR: cannot read number\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // firstly, here we alloc space for first dimension
    A = malloc(n1 * sizeof(float**));

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n1; i += 1) {
        // now we alloc space for second dimension
        A[i] = malloc(n2 * sizeof(float*));
        for (size_t j = 0; j < n2; j += 1) {
            // here we alloc space for third dimension
            A[i][j] = malloc(n3 * sizeof(float));
        }
    }

    // let's ask the user to input all elements into the array
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n1; i += 1) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < n2; j += 1) {
            for (size_t k = 0; k < n3; k += 1) {
                printf("Insert value for A[%zu][%zu][%zu]: ", i, j, k);
                if (scanf("%f", &(A[i][j][k])) != 1) {
                    printf("ERROR: cannot read number\n");
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // now let's print all the numbers that the user has input previously
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n1; i += 1) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < n2; j += 1) {
            for (size_t k = 0; k < n3; k += 1) {
                printf("A[%zu][%zu][%zu] = %f\n", i, j, k, A[i][j][k]);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I've not compiled it, but it should be correct. Take a close look at how allocation has been made.

NOTE: of course, total correctness (e.g.: use of `free()` and avoidance of `scanf()`) has been avoided on purpose.

P.S.: as other users already mentioned, take care to enable warnings for your compiler (e.g.: `-Wall -Wextra` on GCC), because it will simplify debugging very much for you.

Comment: Rather than allocate to the size of type, allocating to the size of the referenced object is less error prone and easier to maintain.  `arr = malloc(n1 * sizeof *arr);`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yes, yours is one good alternative approach.

Comment: @LucaPolito Sorry. But as I told above. I can't change `float A***` to anything else.

Comment: @SecretNumber This answer uses `float***`.  How does that not fulfill your goals?

Comment: @SecretNumber Look better. I haven't changed your `float ***A`, I've just renamed it to `arr`. You can replace `arr` with `A` if you want.

Comment: I can't add anything after `float ***A`  too. This line was fix and cannot edit or add anything.

Comment: @SecretNumber I've renamed `arr` to `A`, the code remains the same.

Comment: `float*** arr = malloc(n1 * sizeof(float**));` I can't do this. But I can if you remove `float***`

Comment: @SecretNumber I've edited the code already.

Comment: @SecretNumber P.S.: `float ***A = ...;` is just a shortcut for `float ***A; A = ...;`